# ul navigation over image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place an ul navigation over an image without success.

```
<header>
   <img src="images/header3.jpg" alt="header">
   <ul>
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Store</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
   </ul>
</header>
```

I've been messing around with different positions such as fixed (not what I'm seeking even thoe it works) and absolute. Also tried to add the image in css instead but does not end up with any good results. Including tried to change most of the tags to divs, tried different tags such as heading elements.

I am trying to get the navigation up at the right top corner ontop of the image.

Note: Why I'm using the  tag before li is simply because of hovering effects.

```
header img {
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

header ul {
position:absolute;

}

header li {
float:left;
list-style-type:none;
font-size:25px;
margin-left:2%;
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid black;
padding:0.5%;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3zgc.jpg as requested.

Comment: Explain in screenshot. What you trying to say? And why top-right? You'll always be navigated to the top left of the image, ie, where the image starts.

Comment: I can't see your `ul` tag. :(

Comment: He is pretty confused, in what he wants to achieve.

Comment: Updated discription, code and did an image upload as requested @Deadpool

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
div.wrapper{width:800px;height:500px;background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/F2UFAV24QII/maxresdefault.jpg");}
div.bar{float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 

<div class="bar"> 
<button>Home</button>
<button>About</button>
<button>Content</button>
</div>
```

> You needed to use background-image feature of CSS3.

Comment: Weeell it seems like im still not fully understood.

I want the navigation bar to be placed in the top right corner, not to take you there. 

Here is a more professional discriptive image https://imgur.com/a/suNdy hopefully that clear things out.

Comment: Look at updated answer. Now, dont say, you didn't want this.

Comment: It is exactly how I wanted it, you finally got me, because of my paint skills it seems..

However I just solved it myself, all thought in a different way, position absolute did actually work out if I for some reason moved my ul tag so it was placed before my img tag.

http://codepen.io/Unkn0wn96/pen/pNZdqP The result, so yes you pinpointed it really well at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Please check updated code here:
http://codepen.io/jasjain/pen/aBjEjg

```
header {
  position: relative;
}

header,
header img {
  width: 100%;
}

header ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 99%;
  padding: 0;
  right: 1%;
  top: 1%;
  text-align: right;
}

header li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 25px;
 margin-left: 2%;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 padding: 1% 3%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

I have added position:realtive; on header, instead of image in the header.
I have also added position properties for UL.